# I want to make something like a custom \dfrac

Tags: amsmath

I use the amsmath package.  To increase the vertical space in the denominator I usually add

```
\vphantom{\overline{THING}}
```

as in

```
\dfrac{this is a}{\vphantom{\overline{fraction}}fraction}
```

How can I get Latex set up so that I can use this fraction format without typing "vphantom" and "overline" every time?  Also, I've been adding a new line to the end of each equation and I would like to not have to type "newline" every time, as in:

```
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{sample}{\vphantom{\overline{fraction}}fraction}
\end{equation}\newline
```

Comment: *Never* add `\newline` after `\end{equation}`.

Comment: also you could use `\frac` here not `\dfrac` (fractions are automatically display style in display math )

Answer (score 1):

A macro is enough

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\yourfrac[2]{\dfrac{#1}{\vphantom{\overline{#2}}#2}} % Need amsmath to work!
\begin{document}
\[\dfrac{AB}{AB}\quad\dfrac{A}{\vphantom{\overline{AB}}AB}\quad\yourfrac{AB}{AB}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

As for the `\newline`, I don't think you should use that. It will produce a blank line which leads to a bad vertical space. Just remove all `\newline` and it will be ok.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you really gain in quality. Anyway, you can look up the definition of `\dfrac` with

```
latexdef -p amsmath \dfrac
```

and get

```
\dfrac:
\long macro:->\genfrac {}{}{}0
```

This suggests the redefinition:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\let\standarddfrac\dfrac

\renewcommand{\dfrac}[2]{%
  \genfrac{}{}{}0{#1}{\vphantom{\overline{T}}{#2}}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\dfrac{1}{2} \quad \standarddfrac{1}{2}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\let\standarddfrac\dfrac` instruction is not necessary, I used it just to show left the new output, right the old one.